# Best way of testing an application which you only know its functionality

Tags: testing, integration-testing

I have received a software application without tests which I'm going to refactor.
The client has shown me how the app it's suppose to work and I have written down all the steps. 
The application is quite a mess: names are not related with the actual propose of the code, there is unused functionality and a long etc. I'm going to refactor it completely but before doing that I wanted to create some tests so I don't break the whole system. I'm going to change the steps in which objects are created because I think it's not user friendly.

I'm wondering what would be the best way of testing in such a case. 
Since I only know the effect of the action of the users, I think feature tests or integration tests would be the best way to go because it's the information I have. On the other hand, as I'm going to change the UI, I think I would need to tests against the database, and that's not what feature tests are suppose to do.

Would it be a good idea to reproduce the scenarios on a browser and then check that the database state it's as I expected?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal approach is you should write tests for a particular portion of the code, then refactor it. This way ,as a bonus, you would get better understanding of the code. But what I've seen in reality is that normally legacy code is so messed up that it is not exactly `testable`. Most of the time code is so highly coupled that unit-testing it becomes a nightmare. If that's the case I think the best approach would be write very high-level Black-Boxed integration tests such that they those tests still work even after you refactor the code.

If writing tests is too much work, just writing tests for the new code only by understanding the original functionality wouldn't be too bad either, since we refactor code to make it testable, and we need to have testable code to refactor makes us stuck in a vicious circle.

And yes you can definitely write tests that interact with database. It is perfectly ok to be not too concerned about the definition of "Unit Tests" as long as the tests are granular. Personally I try to avoid mocking anyway. [Classical vs London School TDD](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/mockists-are-dead-long-live-classicists)

Comment: Yes that is exactly the case. That's why I'm writing high level integration tests. But would it be alright in such a scenario that I check the creation of objects on the database? Since I'm going to change the UI, I think it's the only way of knowing that the steps do what they have to do.